# Select next UL?

Tags: jquery

I have a trigger which needs to grab the next UL element and apply effects to it.

```
 <div id="archives_trigger"><a class="menu_trigger">Monhtly Archives</a></div>
  <ul id="archives_menu">
   <?php wp_get_archives(); ?>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

In this case, the anchor `menu_trigger` is used as the selector. I'm using the following, but something's not right. I'm assuming I'm not using the `next` selector properly.

```
 $('a.menu_trigger').click(
  function () {
    $(this).next(ul).stop(true,true).slideToggle().toggleClass('active');
   }
  );
```

Could you point me in the right direction on how to properly use the `next` selector?

[EDIT] Thank you for editing my incorrect markup. Much appreciated.

Comment: There's a stray `</div>` in your HTML. Is that meant to be there (the one after the `</a>`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the next sibling of the `a` element ([`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) returns the next sibling element, or an empty selection if there are no more siblings).  The `ul` is a sibling of `div#archives_trigger`.  You therefore need to do a call to [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) first:

```
$(this).parent().next('ul').stop(true,true).slideToggle().toggleClass('active');
```

Comment: Perfect! That was the answer! I was not aware that the `next` selector only searched through its own.. family? Anyhow, thank you! I've learned much.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if that's a typo right there, but would you want to try

```
$(this).next('ul')
```

instead of

```
$(this).next(ul)
```

Answer (score 2):

`next` works only in the scope of the current element. You have it into a `<div>`, so it doesn't have any next element.

You have to position yourself over the parent, and then find the next `ul` element:

```
$('a.menu_trigger').click(
    function () {
        $(this).parent().nextAll('ul:first').stop(true,true).slideToggle().toggleClass('active');
    }
);
```

Check the difference between `next` and `nextAll`. If you use `next("ul")` and the first next element is not an `<ul>`, you'll not find any element. On the other hand, if you use `nextAll` with `ul`, you'll get all the next `ul`s, so you need the first of those group of `ul`s.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

[`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) gets the next sibling.  `archives_menu` is a sibling of `archives_trigger`, not `menu_trigger`.

The UL has an ID, why not just use that?  `$('#archives_menu')`

EDIT: Read Jonathon Bolster's comment.  Where should the `</div>` be?  You have one open div tag, but 2 closing tags.  If you remove the `</div>` after `menu_trigger`, the ul will be a sibling of the a.

EDIT 2: You need quotes around your jQuery selector.

Comment: That was my mistake. There's more code after that but I didn't see the closing DIV tag, so I just propped one in without thinking. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, gotta be careful with those closing tags :-P

Answer (score 1):

The UL is not the next sibling in your markup. It is the next sibling of the parent of the trigger. So you can try:

```
 $(this).parent().next("ul").....
```